# matlab: how to save TIFF series?

Tags: image, matlab, save, tiff

Lets say I have a 3D array 'img' (x, y, frame) and want to save it as a TIFF. So far I was doing it by saving one-by-one like this:

```
for K=1:length(img(1, 1, :))
   outputFileName = sprintf('img_%d.tif',K);
   imwrite(img(:, :, K), outputFileName);
end
```

cool, but what if I want to save it as a one tiff stack? How to do it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameter '[append](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-720267)' seems to correspond to what you want.

```
outputFileName = 'img_stack.tif'
for K=1:length(img(1, 1, :))
   imwrite(img(:, :, K), outputFileName, 'WriteMode', 'append');
end
```

EDIT: 
IMAGEJ has problems when opening multipletiffs saved like that. 'Compression','none' is solving the problem :) use:

```
imwrite(img(:, :, K), outputFileName, 'WriteMode', 'append',  'Compression','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred method these days is to use the [`Tiff` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.html) in newer version of MATLAB.

Comment: could you explain how to do that?

Comment: @Nzbuu: the help section is rather obscure when it comes to multipage. If you had a snippet to enlighten us that would be great.